# Why is radioactive activity an important criteria for stating the level of danger of a radioactive waste ? Why not using energy of decay particles?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

The classification of radioactive waste considers two criteria for a given material : its "period" T1/2 and its activity.

I don't understand why the activity (nb of decays per unit of time) is an important information on the level of danger.

Indeed, I would expect that a material could have a huge activity, but with a very tiny energy of the particles produced.

Why don't we consider the *energy* of the decay particles as a criteria for a danger ?

Comment: Energy and type of decay particles is important in determining health effects (ie rad vs rem). Welcome to the generally confusing sets of radiation related units.

Comment: @Jon Custer. Ok. So do you mean that the activity itself is not  a enough criteria to state whether a radioactive waste is dangerous or not ?

Comment: That is correct. For example, alphas generally don’t penetrate past your layer of dead skin. But, breathe in Radon and get alphas in you lungs you are in trouble since there isn’t a dead layer there. You should browse Wiki on rad and rem, and more broadly on radiation units.